# Error while exporting animation

Tags: export

When trying to export a video in the following manner

```
anim = ListAnimate[Table[Graphics[Rectangle[]], {j, 10}]]

Export["anim.mp4", anim, "FrameRate" -> 60, 
 ImageResolution -> 800, Antialiasing -> True]
```

where `anim` is just an example. The code is inspired by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61375/64001), I get the following error message

[image]

`"FrameRate"` is working fine, but I also tried to add the `" "` to `ImageResolution` and `Antialiasing`, with no success. Any idea why, and how to solve this?

I'm using Mathematica 12.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Why do you use `ListAnimate` instead of just exporting the `Table` as `.mp4`?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. How exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The allowed options for `Export` to `mp4` are

[image]

But your command is

```
Export["anim.mp4", anim, "FrameRate" -> 60, 
 ImageResolution -> 800, Antialiasing -> True]
```

Therefore 2 of the options you used do not apply to `mp4`. These are `ImageResolution` and `Antialiasing`. That is why you get the errors.

If you remove these options then it works.

V 12.1 on windows,

reference https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MP4.html