# How to export many images within a For-loop

Tags: export

I'm trying to export a lot of files at one time with a For-loop. I'm using `ToString` so I can number the output files. It's not working. Does anyone know how to export many files with one looping construct?

```
Eq[κ_] := Round[1/2 + 1/2 Cos[(2 π)/κ  y t]]
κ1 = 128*5;
Mask3 = Table[Eq[κ1], {y, 30, 30 + 289}, {t, -100, 100}];
n = 200;
mine = Table[Partition[Table[Mask3[[i, j]], {i, 1, 17*17}], 17], {j, 1, n}];
movie = Table[Image[mine[[p]]], {p, 1, n}]

For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
  Export["OLEDmovie" <> ToString[i] <> ".bmp", movie[[i]], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17826/how-to-automate-generation-of-image-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The well formed `For` loop can achieve your result as m_goldberg has illustrated. You can also use `MapIndexed`, e.g. say wished filename "OLEDmovie001.bmp",...

```
MapIndexed[Export["OLEDmovie"<>IntegerString[First@#2,10,3]<>".bmp",#1]&,movie]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never used MapIndex before but I don't recognize most of what's inside. I'll have to look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have a ill-formed For-loop. Try

```
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++, Export["OLEDmovie" <> ToString[i] <> ".bmp", movie[[i]]]]
```

or

```
Do[Export["OLEDmovie" <> ToString[i] <> ".bmp", movie[[i]]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Both of these worked for me.

Comment: Wow. I'm so sorry I didn't catch that. I was working with so many tables I just put that last part in automatically and the error messages didn't lead me think that was the issue. I'm sorry. Thank you for your help!